# Redux Thunk - Why do I have to call dispatch() twice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Note I'm calling `setStepPositionIndex()` with `dispatch()`.  When I remove `dispatch(...)` to become just `setStepPositionIndex()`
I would expect that the dispatch call within `setStepPositionIndex()` would receive the plain action object it's passed and dispatch it...

**Alternatively**, if I remove the `dispatch()` call within `setStepPositionIndex()` (and keep `dispatch(setStepPositionIndex()`) while explicitly returning plain `actionObj` within it, I would expect a successful dispatch with `dispatch(setStepPositionIndex(actionObj))`

**But yet successful execution of this action creator requires both... why?**

```
   /* actions.js */
import { store } from "../store.js";

store.dispatch(setStepPositionIndex());

export const SET_STEP_POSITION_INDEX = "SET_STEP_POSITION_INDEX";
export const setStepPositionIndex = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const newSteps = getState().goals.currentGoalSteps.map((stepObj, index) => {
      return { ...stepObj, positionIndex: index };
    });
    console.log("newSteps", newSteps);
    /* [{step: "Step3", positionIndex: 0}
      {step: "Step2", positionIndex: 1}
      {step: "Step1", positionIndex: 2}] */

    const actionObj = {
      type: SET_STEP_POSITION_INDEX,
      stepsArr: newSteps
    };
    // Unsuccessful alone ->
    // return actionObj

    // unsuccessful alone (removing dispatch() wrapper from setStepPositionIndex
    //->
    return dispatch(actionObj);
  };
};

/*Reducer.js*/

import * as actions from "../Actions/actions";
import { store } from "../store";
if (action.type === "SET_STEP_POSITION_INDEX") {
  return update(state, {
    currentGoalSteps: { $set: action.stepsArr }
  });
}

/*Store.js */
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { ApolloClient } from "react-apollo";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";
// import { client } from './index'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import * as Goal_Reducer from "./Reducers/Global_Reducer";

const logger = createLogger({
  collapsed: (getState, action, logEntry) => !logEntry.error,
  predicate: (getState, action) => !action.type.includes("@@redux-form")
});

const client = new ApolloClient();

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    goals: Goal_Reducer.goalReducer,
    apollo: client.reducer(),
    form: formReducer
  }),
  {}, //initial state
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(client.middleware(), thunk, logger))
);
```

Comment: why are you using redux-thunk at all in this particular case?

Comment: could you clean up the formatting please? just run your code through https://prettier.io/ (you should be doing that anyways)

Comment: re formatting: good suggestion
re thunk: I'm calling multiple serial actions elsewhere

Comment: To address your other question: that's just how the thunk middleware works. If you have a thunk action creator, it returns another a function that can dispatch and get current state. The reason it gets the ability to dispatch is because you're usually performing some asynchronous task and want to dispatch an action to tell Redux it's finished.

Comment: "If you have a thunk action creator, it returns another a function that can dispatch and get current state."

Right, which is why I don't understand why a simple call to an action creator that produces an action and does the dispatching would need a dispatch it's self.  Simply expect function() => (dispatch) => {return dispatch(obj)}

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name How else would Redux be able to know you want some action performed unless you dispatch?

Comment: Because it is dispatched *within* nested function in the action creator setSuggestedStep() on the actual action (a plain object), not on the action creator, whose main purpose is to return (getState, dispatch)

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name I don't think I'm understanding your question. How I interpret is that you don't understand why you need to call `dispatch` in `dispatch(setStepPositionIndex())` or dispatch in `dispatch(actionObj)` inside the returned function from the action creator, correct? The first case tells Redux you actually want to call the thunk so that the thunk middleware can work its magic. The latter is because you want to dispatch a different action. Redux does not magically dispatch the return value of the return function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179339/discussion-between-zach-is-my-name-and-li357).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, you're just asking why you have to do `store.dispatch(setStepPositionIndex());` and still `dispatch()` inside your thunk. Because `store.dispatch()` is what makes the inner returned thunk function get called with the right arguments, and `dispatch()`ing inside the thunk is what propagates the action to the reducers. I can see how this would be strange to  a newcomer, because `dispatch()` is doing two different things.

First you dispatch the thunk, and the thunk dispatches the action.

**Original answer**

When using `redux-thunk`, and having your action creator returning a function ( `return (dispatch, getState) => {` ), then you must manually call `dispatch()`. You can't simply return from the inner function. That's the point of `redux-thunk`, to control the dispatch(es) manually.

If you don't want to do this, instead of using `getState()`, you could simply dispatch your action from your component with `goals` or `currentGoalSteps` passed in as an argument.

Comment: thunks don't have to be async. The docs show this https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk . Search for "conditional dispatch"

Comment: calling getState() in the thunk is a fine use of a thunk

Comment: but you don't need `redux-thunk` to do this, you can use `mapStateToProps` of the `connect` function to get the state of the store inside the component

Comment: I know, that's in my answer.

Comment: For context, I abstracted out of my question why I'm using a thunk, besides the crucial availability of getState (re-ordering the indices of a todo list after a post for the curious) 

I'm sorry to bother you with a follow up @AndyRay, but can you explain, why I'm not calling dispatch twice in my code? dispatch() written twice seemed enough evidence for me ; )

Comment: because the first `dispatch` doesn't actually reach the store's reducers, it simply execute a function passing `dispatch` et `getState` parameters to be able to `dispatch` the real action later, you can see my answer where I show you the actual code of `redux-thunk`, it doesn't call  `next(action)` when the action is a function, it simply executes the function

Answer (score 2):

Because when using redux-thunk if the action creator returns a function instead of a plain object, the function is executed and its returned value is returned by the `dispatch` function. `setStepPositionIndex()` returns a function not a plain object, so the result of `store.dispatch(setStepPositionIndex())` will be :

```
{
  type: SET_STEP_POSITION_INDEX,
  stepsArr: newSteps
}
```

Actually `redux-thunk` is just a middleware, its code is really simple

```
const thunk = store => next => action =>
   typeof action === 'function'
     ? action(store.dispatch, store.getState)
     : next(action)
```

You can see that when you pass a function, the middleware will execute it (with `dispatch` and `getState` parameters) and returns the function's value.

`redux-thunk` is usefull for dispatching an action under some conditions or after a delay, in your case I don't think you really need `redux-thunk` as you are `dispatching` an action depending on the current state. You can use `mapStateToProps` of your `connected` component to retrieve the state of the store